# Matlab: Same Code different performance

Tags: performance, matlab

I have two `.m` files where I exceute exactly the same code, but with different performance.

```
l(1:101) =(V(2:101)-V(1:100))/del_k;
l(102:201) =(V(102:201)-V(101:200))/del_k;
```

For the lines in question the `profiler` tells me that for the slow code (top line) `mupadmex (MEX-file) 34(calls) 0.296s(total time) 0.293s (self time)`.

But for the fast code it is `display (built-in function) 1(calls) 0.019s(total time) 0.019(self time)`.

Another distinction: in the slow code the profiler lists like a lot of lines, where in the fast one there is only this very one line.

The point is: I'm running an iteration with `n=10000`. The fast code needs for those 10k 2.5sec while, the slow one needs 2secs for one itration (`n=1`).

No idea what to do. The profiler points me to the `Self time (built-ins, overhead, etc.)  1.774s(total time) 98.1%(Time)` which is in the `Children (called functions)` top.

Comment: Have you checked the `class` of `V` and `del_k`? It sounds like the slower one could be symbolic instead of double.

Comment: Cheers mate. You've nailed it.

Comment: @knedlsepp Consider putting it into an answer